# Migrating from Postgres to severless aurora with Postgres 12.5

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to use aurora, but I am using Version 12.5. How can I migrate to aurora?

I think the problem is the version 12.5, so my idea would be to downgrade to 11, but is there not an easier way?

migrate snapshot is grey and cannot be used

Comment: can't export using `pg_dump` and restore using `pg_restore` ? https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-use-pgdump-and-pgrestore-multi-host-enviorment

Comment: I could and it would probably work, but maybe there are easier ways. But thanks, i will try.